# Verifying subscription payment on backend using in_app_purchase library and new App Store api (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store

Does anybody know what is the proper way of verifying receipts now that Apple wants to deprecate verifyReceipt endpoint? I don't still have SSL certificate so that I could open webhook towards Apple Notification servers (still in sandbox), but I'd still like to go through the whole verification flow.

It seems that `serverVerificationData` that is got is completely different than what is through `https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_transaction_info` so I'm stuck if I can even use the data in any way that is being received through the purchase stream by the in_app_purchase library.